# I am not able to build it using yarn

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to build my react app using yarn run build;prod

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
./node_modules/map-age-cleaner/dist/index.js:15
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, could you please review/reconsider your question to match these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? For example, by providing more details about the error, and provide ways for others to reproduce the error. That would really help others to provide you quality help, and it would be of most benefit for the entire community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not Yarn problem you just spell it wrong.
Instead using `yarn run build` use `yarn build`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yarn has nothing to do with *minification*.
Minification depends to webpack/parcel or the bundler you are using.